# Qt: Listing file aliases in the directory

Tags: file, qt, alias

I am trying to list all alias files in Mac Osx using the Qt. I am using the following function:

```
QString QDir::fromNativeSeparators ( const QString & pathName )
```

By specifying the relative path to a directory. It lists only the normal files and skips the aliases.

Please let me know if there is a better way to list both the normal and alias files using Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QDirIterator, Qt documentation is here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdiriterator.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While the information at the target URL may answer the question, we prefer the answer to be *here on our site*, with the link provided as a further reference. Please include relevant information from your source here. [Read more at meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259)